# composer.phar opens in notepad instead of running

Tags: windows, symfony, composer-php

I'm trying to install Symfony and some bundles in a new computer.

I initialize the project and create a database.

However, I also want to download `DoctrineFixturesBundle` and ´DoctrineMigrationsBundle`.

I'm using XAMPP, so I do:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs>composer.phar require doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle
```

And then it opens "composer.phar" in a notepad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot that you need to call composer from `php` interpreter.

```
C:\whateverthepathis\php.exe C:\xampp\htdocs>composer.phar require doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle
```

Or just install composer globally [using its installer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#using-the-installer).

Answer (score 0):

Install `Composer` with this command;

`php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php`

and you can use `php composer require doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle`